# Can't read property of length undefined for last value read from file

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am trying to read a text file that has content like

```
$A,12.23,21.23

$A,12.21,21.22

$A,12.21,21.24
```

And so on.

If the file has 6 lines of text, it reads the 6 lines and then The console shows

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.**

I am new to JS, anyone could point out what's going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Leaflet Label</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.3/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.3/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:relative;height:500px ;top:50; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>

<script>
$(window).resize(function() {
   $('#map').height($(window).height() / 1.5);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');

</script>

<script> $(window).ready(function() { $('#map').height($(window).height() / 1.5); }); </script>


</head>
<body>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-label/v0.2.1/leaflet.label.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-label/v0.2.1/leaflet.label.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<div id='map'></div>

<input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<img id='output'>
<script>

  L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGVnYXN1cyIsImEiOiJjaWd1bjlvdmIwN3Izd3dtMDluYW1lMGlrIn0.QTR6xEpvu5bsXGeYn5jgjg';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([15.199358, 73.626172], 17);

  var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){

      var text = reader.result;
      var line_points = [];

      var res = text.split("\r\n");

      for(i=0;i<res.length;i++)
      {

        if(res[i]!="")
        {
        var inside_array = res[i].split(",");
        console.log(" Lat : " + inside_array[1] + " Lon : " + inside_array[2]);
        var arr1 = [inside_array[1],inside_array[2]];
        line_points.push(arr1);
        }
        //L.marker([inside_array[1], inside_array[2]]).bindLabel('P1').addTo(map);
      }
      var polyline_options = {  color: '#000' };

        L.polyline(line_points, polyline_options).addTo(map);
        console.log(line_points.length);

    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit :
Error Produced

To reproduce the data use that code ( make a .html file ) and run it, it will ask you to upload a file, Fill the content as below and upload the file, the error will show in the console.

$P,17.2335,21.12547

$P,17.23351,21.125471

$P,17.23352,21.125472

$P,17.23353,21.125473

$P,17.23354,21.125474

[image: SO_]

Comment: I'm not sure if that access token is sensitive or not, but you may want that to be hidden...

Comment: Is something missing from the post? Which line gets the error? I don't see how the error is possible, since the only times you're doing `.length` are in the context of arrays.

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/cLfq4he5/

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 : That is the public token from the mapbox website. But thanks for the advice, appreciate it.

Comment: @Jacob the error is caused by leaflet-src.js so i am guessing something is wrong in the line_points area. The code works well with the Marker but not with the Poly Lines

Comment: @guest271314 updated Script. 
Run my HTML code and upload the file as requested.

Comment: @user2967920 Error appear at `Line 1311, Column 1` "mapbox.js"  ?

Comment: @guest271314 Sorted, Check Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr1 = [inside_array[1],inside_array[2]];
```

Should be changed to

```
var arr1 = new L.LatLng(inside_array[1], inside_array[2]);
line_points.push(arr1);
```

It needs an Array of LatLng not 2 strings.

[Reference](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.1/l-polyline/)